# What is the diffrence between window 2008 server 32bits and 64 bits editions when I want to deploy an image?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I want to deploy a windows 2008 32 bit image but I want to know that what is different between 32bit and 64 bit when I want to build the 32bit image.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference beacause IF YOU DEPLOY A 32 bit image YOU CAN NOT BUILD A 64 bit image. That simple.

That said, deploying 32 bit images these days is negligent. Go 64 bit - 64 bit operating systems can see all your memory (32 bit is limited to MAXIMUM 4 GB, most likely about 3.5), and 64 bit can run 32 bit programs.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment is the same whether the image is 64 bit or 32 bit.  You can deploy the images from the same deployment server.